# How do I test the credentials which saved in IOS keychain?

Tags: iphone, keychain

As a tester, I want to test the credentials which saved in IOS keychain. 
scenarios which App can not contact the keychain, Crashed credentials (how to crash?), does the correct credentials use in all the times, Does the credentials remove when the app close and uninstall... etc. How do I do that as a tester?

thanks

Comment: Did you find solution, I want to update ios keychain to simulate authorized state

Comment: Unfortunately not